# Are there left hand cartridges for Delta two handle faucets?

Tags: delta

Is there a left hand faucet cartridge for delta-delex two handle faucets? Or are all cartridges interchangeable?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I don't think this falls under "shopping advice". OP isn't asking if one is better than the other or where to find them, he's asking if the "left" and "right" part are interchangeable. Of course, my suggestion would be to search the interwebz for the manufacturer/model number, find a parts list and look there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are cartridges supplied in left and right configuration. No, not all cartridges are interchangeable.